# How to remove columns and rows at certain indexes in numpy, at the same time

Tags: python, numpy

I've such a square matrix:

```
[[0, 516, 226, 853, 1008, 1729, 346, 1353, 1554, 827, 226, 853, 1729, 1008],
[548, 0, 474, 1292, 1442, 2170, 373, 1801, 1989, 1068, 474, 1292, 2170, 1442],
[428, 466, 0, 1103, 1175, 1998, 226, 1561, 1715, 947, 0, 1103, 1998, 1175],
[663, 1119, 753, 0, 350, 1063, 901, 681, 814, 1111, 753, 0, 1063, 350],
[906, 1395, 1003, 292, 0, 822, 1058, 479, 600, 1518, 1003, 292, 822, 0],
[1488, 1994, 1591, 905, 776, 0, 1746, 603, 405, 1676, 1591, 905, 0, 776],
[521, 357, 226, 1095, 1167, 1987, 0, 1552, 1705, 1051, 226, 1095, 1987, 1167],
[1092, 1590, 1191, 609, 485, 627, 1353, 0, 422, 1583, 1191, 609, 627, 485],
[1334, 1843, 1436, 734, 609, 396, 1562, 421, 0, 1745, 1436, 734, 396, 609],
[858, 1186, 864, 1042, 1229, 1879, 984, 1525, 1759, 0, 864, 1042, 1879, 1229],
[428, 466, 0, 1103, 1175, 1998, 226, 1561, 1715, 947, 0, 1103, 1998, 1175],
[663, 1119, 753, 0, 350, 1063, 901, 681, 814, 1111, 753, 0, 1063, 350],
[1488, 1994, 1591, 905, 776, 0, 1746, 603, 405, 1676, 1591, 905, 0, 776],
[906, 1395, 1003, 292, 0, 822, 1058, 479, 600, 1518, 1003, 292, 822, 0]]
```

And I need to remove say `a1` `a2` and `a3` indexed columns and rows at the sametime. How can I do this? What is the neat way?

Note that, I need to get another square matrix. Both rows and columns at the same index should be removed. Also note that, when you remove a row/column, indexes get shifted. Either I need to shift e.g. `a1`, `a2`, `a3` too or do something more clever.

### An example case

The square matrix:

```
[[10,11,12,13],
 [14,15,16,17],
 [18,19,20,21],
 [22,23,24,25]]
```

remove 1st and 3rd indexes and the result is:

```
[[10,12],
 [18,20]]
```

Comment: Please add an mcve https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: check my approach using `np.ix_`

Comment: `np.delete` can be used to first delete the rows, and then the columns.  I don't think it makes a difference whether you do the steps sequentially or simultaneously.  But it isn't hard to construct indices that will select the desired rows and columns at the same time.  That's really what you are doing when deleting - selecting all-but.

Comment: `np.delete` operates only on a single axis though. and you can create the column and row indexes to delete (or to keep) using `np.ix_`. I benchmarked applying np.delete over both axis sequentially and its super slow as compared to other approaches `2 s ± 348 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`. Trying to find if this method can be applied to both axis simultaneously.

Answer (score 3):

If you want numpy only and assuming the array is always squared:

```
a = np.array([[10,11,12,13], 
[14,15,16,17], 
[18,19,20,21], 
[22,23,24,25]])    
valid = [r for r in range(a.shape[0]) if r not in [1,3]] 
a[valid][:,valid]
>>>array([[10, 12],
   [18, 20]])
```

Comment: Input is always squared so this numpy alternative is also a good answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are open to other packages, [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/)can make it easy:

```
import pandas as pd

to_drop = [a1,a2,a3]
out = pd.DataFrame(a).drop(to_drop).drop(to_drop, axis=1).to_numpy()
```

---

**Update**: output of the code on sample data

```
array([[10, 12],
   [18, 20]])
```

Comment: does this ensure [a1,a2,a3]'s are the same when removing rows and after columns?

Answer (score 2):

Try this method in numpy. `np.ix_` creates a meshgrid for you to index the numpy array columns and rows. The list of indexes can simply be created by taking the `set.difference` between the range of rows in square matrix and the list of indexes of row/columns you want to remove -

```
sqm = np.array([[10,11,12,13],
 [14,15,16,17],
 [18,19,20,21],
 [22,23,24,25]])

rem = [1,3] #Rows/columns to remove

idx = list(set(range(sqm.shape[0])).difference(rem))
print('Rows/columns to keep:',idx)

output = sqm[np.ix_(idx,idx)]
print(output)
```

```
Rows/columns to keep: [0, 2]
 
array([[10, 12],
       [18, 20]])
```

---

**EDIT:** Benchmarking results are added below for square matrix 10000X10000 and ~500 row/columns to remove. (macbook pro 13)

```
sqm = np.random.random((10000,10000))
rem = np.unique(np.random.randint(0,10000,size=500))
```

- *Quang Hoang's Approach* - 841 ms ± 8.19 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
- *MBeale's Approach* - 1.62 s ± 48.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
- *Akshay Sehgal's Approach* - 655 ms ± 19.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Comment: It is interesting that `MBeale` approach is slower than `Quang Hoang`'s pandas approach.

Comment: Because of the explicit for loop, and boolean indexing 2 times `[valid][:,valid]`. Quang Hoang's approach has the heaviest step as the conversion to pandas probably. Other pandas functions should be fairly optimized.